# How to force the taskbar to refresh an app's shortcut icon

Tags: c#

The method below takes as one of the parameters the name of an icon (`string newIcon`) to update a shortcut in the Taskbar (`currentLink.SetIconLocation(@$"C:\Meus Programas\_Ícones\{newIcon}", 0);`).

But the icon image is not being changed immediately when the method is executed. Is there any way to force Explorer to refresh the shortcut icon?

```
 private void ChangeShortcutLinkTarget(string shortcutFullPath, string newTarget, string newIcon)
            {
                // Load the shortcut.
                Shell32.Shell shell = new Shell32.Shell();
                Shell32.Folder folder = shell.NameSpace(Path.GetDirectoryName(shortcutFullPath));
                Shell32.FolderItem folderItem = folder.Items().Item(Path.GetFileName(shortcutFullPath));
                Shell32.ShellLinkObject currentLink = (Shell32.ShellLinkObject)folderItem.GetLink;

                // Assign the new path here. This value is not read-only.
                currentLink.Path = newTarget;
                currentLink.SetIconLocation(@$"C:\Meus Programas\_Ícones\{newIcon}", 0);

                // Save the link to commit the changes.
                currentLink.Save();

            }
```